# std::shared_ptr internals, weak count more than expected

Tags: c++, stl, shared-ptr

In one [episode](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Advanced-STL/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Advanced-STL-1-of-n) (35:00) of Advanced STL series, Stephan T Lavavej showed that `_Weaks`, the counter whose value of 0 determines when to delete the `_Ref_count` structure, equals the number of alive `weak_ptr`, plus 1 if there are alive `shared_ptrs`. He explained that it is necessary because of thread safety: if `_Weaks` only equaled the number of `weak_ptr` then when last `weak_ptr` would go out of scope it would be also necessary to check `_Uses`, the counter of alive `shared_ptr`s, to check if `_Ref_count` can be deleted. And this is unacceptable because of lack of atomicity.

Assuming that `_Uses` = number of alive `shared_ptr`s, `_Weaks` = number of alive `weak_ptr`s, imagine we have the following scenario:

- (`_Uses` = 0, `_Weaks` = **1**): last `weak_ptr` goes out of scope, decrement `_Weaks`
- (`_Uses` = 0, `_Weaks` = **0**): if `_Uses` is equal to 0, delete `_Ref_count` structure

What, in multithreaded application, can go wrong, which forces us to use *`_Weak` = number of alive `weak_ptr` + (number of `shared_ptr` ? 1 : 0)* implementation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Imagine the following scenario. Thread **A** holds a `shared_ptr`, thread **B** holds a corresponding `weak_ptr`. So in your implementation, we have `_Uses == 1` and `_Weaks == 1`.

There are two possible implementations for the smart pointer destructors, both with problems.

## Implementation 1: decrement, then check

**B**'s `weak_ptr` is destroyed. Decrements `_Weaks`. We have `_Uses == 1`, `_Weaks == 0`. **B** prepares to check `_Uses`, but ...

Context switch.

**A**'s `shared_ptr` is destroyed. Decrements `_Uses`. We have `_Uses == 0`, `_Weaks == 0`. Begin destruction of `_Ref_count`.

Context switch.

**B** now get round to checking `_Uses`. It's 0. Begin destruction of `_Ref_count`.

Both threads are now in the process of destroying `_Ref_count`. Not good.

## Implementation 2: check, then decrement

**B**'s `weak_ptr` is destroyed. Check `_Uses`. It's 1, no destruction will happen. **B** prepares to decrement `_Weaks`, but ...

Contex switch.

**A**'s `shared_ptr` is destroyed. Checks `_Weaks`. It's 1, no destruction will happen. Decrement `_Uses`. We have `_Uses == 0`, `_Weaks == 1`. Done.

Context switch.

**B** now gets round to decrement `_Weaks`. We have `_Uses == 0`, `_Weaks == 0`. Nothing else to do.

We have leaked the `_Ref_count`. Not good.

Comment: Ok, I see now. It is resolved by delegating of removing `_Ref_count` **only** to scenario when `_Weaks == 1 -> 0`.

Comment: @user2551229 Yes. The point is that you only have *one* variable controlling the lifetime, not two.

Comment: " B now gets round to decrement _Weaks. We have _Uses == 0, _Weaks == 0. Nothing else to do".  -> it should be " _Uses == 1, _Weaks == 0".

Comment: @Angew Using `_Weak` = number of alive `weak_ptr` + (number of `shared_ptr` ? 1 : 0)  could make **Implementation 1: decrement, then check** work, but couldn't make **Implementation 2** work, right?